# Seriously, do Facebook thumbnails actually work?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

I see a TON of questions on here and around the web in general about how to set these Facebook thumbnails. Most answers involve the og: meta tags, but I'm just not convinced this works. To be fair, it could be Facebook's fault, but I'm pretty sure I have the code written out properly. Can anyone tell me if something is wrong?

The website: http://nopadc.com/

Here is what I have in my header.php file (this is a Wordpress website BTW):

```
<?php if( get_option('spark_logo') ): ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_option('spark_logo'); ?>">
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo get_option('spark_logo'); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>">
```

And here is what is output in the source:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://nopadc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo-nopa.png">
<link rel="image_src" href="http://nopadc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo-nopa.png">
<meta property="og:title" content="NoPA">
<meta property="og:description" content="An American brasserie in the heart of Penn Quarter.">
```

I have made sure the logo URL is correct. I have tried this without the < link > tag and tried linking to the website on Facebook on the first, second, and third day after the change. The same goes for having the < link > tag. I noticed some solutions mentioned that Facebook could take up to a day to rescrape for images, that's why I gave it three days with each change.

In any case I cannot tell what is wrong with this code. Unless there is some other Javascript library to include on the website, what am I missing? Or is this just Facebook not scraping the site correctly?

Comment: I'm starting to think that Facebook just has a cached version of the images for this URL, so maybe it just won't update itself for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously doubt there's anything wrong with Facebook.

Try using this plugin: [Easy Facebook Share Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-facebook-share-thumbnails/)